# error occured while consuming a webservice hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, web-services, azure-web-app-service

I have created a web service which is internally consuming  SSDS service (https://database.windows.net/soap/v1/).
I was able to sucessfully host my web service in cloud also placed client access policy and cross doamin policy in place.
But when I am trying to consume this web service in Silverlight hosted on cloud it its throwing exception  :-

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://xxx.cloudapp.net:20000/xxx.asmx?wsdl'.
There was an error downloading 'http://xxx.cloudapp.net:20000/xxx.asmx?wsdl'.
The request failed with HTTP status 502: Proxy Error ( Connection refused ).
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://xxx.cloudapp.net/xxx.asmx'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://xxx.cloudapp.net/xxx.asmx'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

What can be the problem?

When I hit the hosted web service on browser i am able to see the then  service desciption properly.

```
'http://xxx.cloudapp.net:20000/xxx.asmx?wsdl'
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/69f744c2-5da7-40d5-8e08-268435174520.